# NavigationBar is not appearing on my ViewController

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I have a UIViewController that is presented modally. The UIViewController is inside of a UINavigationController.

```
// Implement viewDidLoad to do additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    saveButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Save" 
                                                  style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered 
                                                  target:self 
                                                  action:@selector(saveButtonClicked:)]; 


    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = saveButton;
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:(102.0/255.0) green:(20.0/255.0) blue:(11.0/255.0) alpha:1];
    self.title = @"Login";
    //toolbar.tintColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:(102.0/255.0) green:(20.0/255.0) blue:(11.0/255.0) alpha:1];
}
```

Why isn't my navbar appearing with the text Login and a save button to the right?

Comment: How about the tintColor, is it correct? Does the navigationBar appears at all?

Comment: Is your view controller inside a navigation controller (UINavigationController)? Please post the code that shows your view controller (pushes it to navigation controller).

Comment: Agree with Michael; we need to see more code.  If you are using a XIB or a default template, please mention that as well.

Comment: Updated question with more details

Comment: off topic but still: if you alloc, please also (auto)release.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you may be presenting the view controller instead of the navigation controller.  Your code to present the view controller you've described should look something like this:

```
MyViewController *viewController = [[MyViewController alloc] init];
UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:viewController];
[self presentModalViewController:navController animated:YES];
[viewController release];
[navController release];
```

Answer (score 0):

You set the properties after the nib is loaded, but you probably need to do it after/while it is pushed.